# iOS12 Chinese Keyboard(zh-Hans and zh-Hant) causing app crash (TextFiled in UISearchBar/UIAlertView/UIAlertViewController)

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, textfield, uialertview, ios12

My app has this issue after upgrading to iOS 12. App will crash whenever the native Chinese keyboard or third party Chinese Keyboard is invoked. Chinese hand-writing keyboard does not cause crash.

The app is localised for English and Chinese, so the 'AppleLanguages' in the UserDefaults changes from time to time upon user modifications.

The code used for searchBar is simple.

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
self.searchBar.delegate = self
```

The exception message is:

> -[NSNull isSecureContentCandidate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e39f99a0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isSecureContentCandidate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e39f99a0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1b3ce3ef8 0x1b2eb1a40 0x1b3bfb154 0x1b3ce9810 0x1b3ceb4bc 0x1e030ed18 0x1e039472c 0x1e0394380 0x1e03e7030 0x1e0394330 0x1e03e9064 0x1e03e7774 0x1e03e7784 0x1b47935a0 0x1b3c725b8 0x1b3c72538 0x1b3c71e1c 0x1b3c6cce8 0x1b3c6c5b8 0x1b5ee0584 0x1e0567558 0x100575d34 0x1b372cb94)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I have tried to resolve the crash by forcing app to use alphabet keyboard, which disabled Chinese input for the pages having this issue.

```
self.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.alphabet
```

Thank you in advance~!

Answer (score 1):

Crash fixed by adjusting local NSNull extension.